# How do I change the displayed time format after NSTimer is initiated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, nsdateformatter

I'm starting out my iOS experience with a project that incorporates a large clock as a portion of the user interface.  When I try to incorporate a user-adjustable toggle to switch from 12-hr to 24-hr time format, I get issues. After the initial user change of the on-screen toggle, the displayed time "flickers" between the 2 formats.

My approach:

1. `viewDidLoad` sets the attribute used for 12-hr time format and calls the startTimer method
2. startTimer method:   `NSDateFormatter` is set.  `NSTimer` is initiated with scheduled interval, passing the **DateFormatter** to the upDateTime method
3. updateTimer method checks current time and sets the on-screen
4. If the user, clicks the on-screen 12-hr/24-hr segmented control, the `IBAction` invalidates the timer and passes the desired time format attribute to the startTimer method

Testing/Observations:

- Code below shows an approach where I modified the time format by setting the Locale and passing it to the **DateFormatter**.   I thought this might be an issue conflicting with the device Locale.  I tried using a custom Date Formatter   (example  @"hh:mm a") instead and had the same flickering issue.
- `NSTimer` scheduled interval shows as 1 sec.  I have this for testing, but saw same behavior at 0.1 sec.
- `NSLog` calls within the updateTime method show that the **DateFormatter** object id and the displayed time are changing between successive loops, even though the user did not adjust the toggle switch.
- I suspect this may have something to do with how the Timer is initiated and stopped.  Perhaps the old "calls" with the previous format is still running in the background?  I experimented with moving the `[updateTimer invalidate]` to a couple of places in the methods without success

Root Question:
Any suggestions or better approach to having an on-screen clock with a user switch for 12-hr vs. 24-hr time format?  Any reason why the displayed time format keeps cycling?

Code:

```
- (void)startTimer:(NSString *)displayedClockMode {

    // using locale within formatter overrides device system behavior chosen by user
    NSString *localeValue = nil;
    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    if([displayedClockMode isEqual:@"12-hr"]){
        //then 12 hr format - based on US locale
        localeValue = @"en_US_POSIX";
        //[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    }
    else { //assume no other value exists
        // 24 hr format - based on GB locale
        localeValue = @"en_GB";
        //[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    }

    NSLocale *clockLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:localeValue];
    [timeFormatter setLocale:clockLocale];
    [timeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    //stop timer before re-starting with new format
    [self.updateTimer invalidate];
    self.updateTimer = nil;

    NSTimer *updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:timeFormatter repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)updateTimer {

    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];

    NSLog(@"old display time: %@",self.displayedTime.text);

    self.displayedTime.text = [updateTimer.userInfo stringFromDate:currentTime];

    NSLog(@"new display time: %@",self.displayedTime.text);
    NSLog(@"new timeformatter: %@",updateTimer.userInfo);

}


- (IBAction)displayedTimeMode:(id)sender {

    [self.updateTimer invalidate];
    self.updateTimer = nil;

    NSString *timeFormat = nil;
    if(self.displayedTimeToggle.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        //if 0, then 12 hr format
        timeFormat = @"12-hr";
    }
    else {
        // is 1, 24 hr format
        timeFormat = @"24-hr";
    }

    [self startTimer:timeFormat];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have two different `updateTimers` -- `self.updateTimer` the class variable and `updateTimer` the local variable. You're invalidating the class variable, but initializing and running multiple local `NSTimers` with different locales during each call to `startTimer`. That's why you see this "flickering" -- it's because multiple `NSTimer`s are setting the label using different localeValues.

To fix this, change:

```
NSTimer *updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:timeFormatter repeats:YES];
```

to

```
self.updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:timeFormatter repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  I thought there was a strong chance I was just making a silly mistake.   All good now.